# How can removing faces increase file size?

Tags: mesh, blend-files

This isn't so much a "how to do something" question, but the issue is: I was working on a model and deleted a bunch of faces that was overlapping with another mesh, and then I joined the mesh to the first one, and then when I save the model is up about 200 MB for some reason. How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe try File > Clean Up > Unused Data-Blocks, close and open again?

Comment: Tried that, it said there was nothing to purge. It is a model imported from Daz, not sure if that might have any effect on it.